# Sql - IN operator Behavior Returns Various results

Tags: mysql, sql

Sql IN operator not behaves accordingly.

```
select * from products where product_code  IN (530121,530125)
```

and the result comes also with the product code **530121-1,530121-2** and **530125-1**

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you saying that `IN(530121-1)` returns the product with id = 530120?

Comment: Strings are not integers. 530121-1 = 530120

Comment: Datatype for product_code? Use the same in the in-clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comparing one string with another, then you need to wrap that string in inverted commas...

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_code  IN ('530121','530125')
```